# Is Laravel web.php still relevant?

Tags: laravel

I am a beginner in Laravel, I've been seeing a lot of people use RestAPI and therefore uses api.php in laravel routes instead of web.php.

I am currently working on a project using laravel and has only CRUD functionalities but I started it out with all my routes in web.php.

Is using web.php routes in laravel still relevant?

I've asked some of my colleagues and they did answer me that using api.php is now the big thing when creating projects. I just want to learn what other developers think about this as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what are you trying to build, if you are trying to build a website, use `web.php` for your routes as the middleware applied to them by default are different from the ones on `api.php`. If you are trying to build a REST API use `api.php`.
These are made for different goals, not to replace one with another.

`web.php` and `api.php` are just php files to group routes applying middlewares to them already written for you, you can check its definitions on [app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php) and you can modify them, delete or create your own.
Just the framework has already defined these two for you that may be way too common for making the user define them every time, [web routes recibe a middleware group called web, and a middleware group called api, both described in the default middleware groups from the official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware). As it is mentioned there:

> Out of the box, Laravel comes with web and api middleware groups that contain common middleware you may want to apply to your web UI and API routes

The api group just includes throttling while the web group includes things you will need on a web UI route like CsrfToken, Session, Cookies, etc...

Comment: May I know the scope of what you meant by website?

Comment: I'm extending my response for explaining this

Answer (score 0):

you can make own routing file as your requirement in app/providers/RouteServiceProvider
In my case i created admin.php

```php
protected function mapAdminRoutes()
    {
        Route::group([
            'middleware' => ['web', 'admin', 'auth:admin'],
            'prefix' => 'admin',
            'as' => 'admin.',
            'namespace' => $this->namespace,
        ], function ($router) {
            require base_path('routes/admin.php');
        });
    }

public function map()
    {
        $this->mapApiRoutes();

        $this->mapWebRoutes();

        $this->mapAdminRoutes();
    }
```